# UI Test and stresstest

Tags: windows-8

I have found a lot of references to UI automation for modern UI applications. But I'm not searching a way to record click/touch paths rather than a program that just simulates random input (from single to multi touch). Somehow comparable to the stress test tool that is available for Microsoft Pixelsense. Does anyone knows a tool?